# How to implement auto complete using jquery marcopolo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement marcopolo, which is a jquery plugin to do auto complete.

Here are my two issues.

1) If I type a single letter or any word, all values for "Direction" will appear, which is not correct. I would like, for example, if I search for "Up", any words with those two letters will appear.

2) If a user searches for "Up" and they hit enter or hit the submit button, they should be taken to the URL associated with that word.

Github reference: https://github.com/jstayton/jquery-marcopolo
Marcopolo example: http://jstayton.github.io/jquery-marcopolo/example1.html

And here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrwgwJ

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="autoCom" id="autoCom"><input type="submit" class="send">
```

CSS

```
ol {position: absolute; top: 20px;}
ol.mp_list {list-style-type: none;}
```

JS

```
$(function(){

$('#autoCom').marcoPolo({
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ygdk',
        minChars: 1,
        submitOnEnter: true,
            formatData: function (data) {
                return data; //possible issue
            },
        formatItem: function (data, $item) {
            return data.Direction;
            },
            onSelect: function (data, $item) {
        //window.location = data.URL;
        this.val(data.Direction);
        window.open(data.URL,'_blank');
            }
    });

});
```

Thanks ahead for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending the "q" variable with the content of the `<input/>` element but the page you configured as a JSON response isn't filtering anything with that "q" variable, so, you will always get the same result.

```
[{"Direction":"Up","URL":"http://www.google.com"},{"Direction":"Left","URL":"http://www.cnn.com"},{"Direction":"Right","URL":"http://www.engadget.com"},{"Direction":"Down","URL":"http://www.twitter.com"},{"Direction":"Upward","URL":"http://www.facebook.com"},{"Direction":"Leftwing","URL":"http://www.snapfish.com"},{"Direction":"Rightwing","URL":"http://www.gizmodo.com"},{"Direction":"Downward","URL":"http://www.fox.com"}]
```

Comment: Sorry, new to this JSON thing. I'm looking at the code on https://gist.github.com/jstayton/1008099. Just like line 35 of the code, do I need to add "param: 'query'" in the JS? Or is there something that I need to update in the JSON file? Thanks!

Comment: Marcopolo sends the stuff you type on the textbox to the server assuming that with this the server will filter your output, but it never gets filtered, then the server always returns the same.